# Why do we use tf.name_scope()

Tags: tensorflow

I've been reading the tutorials on TensorFlow where they have written

```
with tf.name_scope('read_inputs') as scope:
    # something
```

The example

```
a = tf.constant(5)
```

and

```
with tf.name_scope('s1') as scope:
    a = tf.constant(5)
```

seem to have the same effect. So, why do we use `name_scope`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't see the use case for reusing constants but here is some relevant information on scopes and variable sharing.

**Scopes**

- `name_scope` will add scope as a prefix to all operations
- `variable_scope` will add scope as a prefix to all variables and operations

**Instantiating Variables**

- `tf.Variable()` constructer prefixes variable name with current `name_scope` and `variable_scope`
- `tf.get_variable()` constructor ignores `name_scope` and only prefixes name with the current `variable_scope`

For example:

```py
with tf.variable_scope("variable_scope"):
     with tf.name_scope("name_scope"):
         var1 = tf.get_variable("var1", [1])

with tf.variable_scope("variable_scope"):
     with tf.name_scope("name_scope"):
         var2 = tf.Variable([1], name="var2")
```

Produces

```py
var1 = <tf.Variable 'variable_scope/var1:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>

var2 = <tf.Variable 'variable_scope/name_scope/var2:0' shape=(1,) dtype=string_ref>
```

**Reusing Variables**

- Always use `tf.variable_scope` to define the scope of a shared variable
- The easiest way to do reuse variables is to use the `reuse_variables()` as shown below

```py
with tf.variable_scope("scope"):
    var1 = tf.get_variable("variable1",[1])
    tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
    var2=tf.get_variable("variable1",[1])
assert var1 == var2
```

- `tf.Variable()` always creates a new variable, when a variable is constructed with an already used name it just appends `_1`, `_2` etc. to it - which can cause conflicts :(

Answer (score 27):

They are not the same thing.

```
import tensorflow as tf
c1 = tf.constant(42)
with tf.name_scope('s1'):
    c2 = tf.constant(42)
print(c1.name)
print(c2.name)
```

prints

```
Const:0
s1/Const:0
```

So as the name suggests, the scope functions create a scope for the *names* of the ops you create inside. This has an effect on how you refer to tensors, on reuse, on how the graph shows in TensorBoard and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please tell me how to reuse c1 and c2?

Comment: @VibhorKanojia by defining them as tf.Variables?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to use some loose but easy-understanding language to explain.

**name scope**

usually used to group some variables together in an op. That is, it gives you an explanation on how many variables are included in this op. However, for these variables, their existence is not considered. You just know, OK, to complete this op, I need to prepare this, this and this variables. Actually, in using `tensorboard`, it helps you bind variables together so your plot won't be messy.

**variable scope**

think about this as a drawer. Compared with **name space**, this is of more "physical" meaning, because such drawer truly exists; in the contrary, **name space** just helps understand which variables are included.

Since **variable space** "physically" exists, so it constrains that since this variable is already there, you can't redefine it again and if you want to use them multiple times, you need to indicate `reuse`.