# Do variable_scope and name_scope have any purpose in TensorFlow 2 with eager execution?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, eager-execution

In TensorFlow 2, eager execution is the default execution. There is no need for annoying sessions or placeholders.

There are so many questions related to `name_scope`, `variable_scope`, etc., on Stack Overflow, for example, [What is the difference between variable_scope and name_scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34215746/3924118), [What's the difference of name scope and a variable scope in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35919020/3924118), [What are the practical differences between the variable_scope and name_scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45850327/3924118) and [Why do we use tf.name_scope()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42708989/3924118), because people understandably do not get the idea behind these functions and their purpose. Essentially, these functions are used to name the variables in the underlying computational graph.

Do `variable_scope`, `name_scope`, etc., have any purpose or usage in TensorFlow 2 with eager execution? If so, can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

In TensorFlow 2 with Eager execution, you can still use `tf.name_scope` which was moved to TF2.

Below is an example.

```
with tf.name_scope("foo"):
    with tf.name_scope("bar"):
        v = tf.Variable([0], dtype=tf.float32, name="v")
        assert v.name == "foo/bar/v:0"
```

But since Variable is in Tensorflow 2 has many changes and improvements by addressing drawbacks like `variables reusing`, `reliance on global scopes`.
It is not really necessary to use `variable_scope` with these changes to the Variables.

But if you still need to use variable_scope you can use it in the following way.

> `to control variable naming users can use tf.name_scope + tf.Variable`

You can follow community RFC [Variables in TensorFlow 2.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180817-variables-20.md) for detailed information on all the major changes on Variables from Tensorflow 1 to Tensorflow 2